# how to print array elements using pointer in c?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

please anyone check is there any issue in my code
i am using *(ptr+i) in loop to print elements of array but it is not giving desired output !!
someone please help me out!!
taking input and output of array using pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int *ptr = &arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("enter the value of array at place %d : ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("value of array at place %d is %d\n", i + 1, *(ptr + i));
        // ptr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After first loop, `ptr` no longer points to any address of array. Reset `ptr` variable to `&arr[0]` after first and before second for loop.

Comment: For the first element of the array you don't need to assign with & operator you can directly assign the pointer ` int *ptr = arr;`.

Comment: (1) after the first loop, `ptr` needs to be assigned to `arr` again, since it is now pointing to `arr+5`; that is, the printing starts at `arr[5]` in the second loop (2) `&arr[0]` is equivelent to `arr` (3) `*(ptr + i)` is equivelent to `ptr[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

After you modify the ptr, you miss the first element address of the array. You need to reassign the first element address before entering the printer loop. See the fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int *ptr = arr; // You can assign an array of the first element directly using the identifier.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("enter the value of array at place %d : ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    ptr = arr; // This line was missing
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("value of array at place %d is %d\n", i + 1, *(ptr + i));
        // ptr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```